# How long it takes to check a checkbox

Tags: fittslaw

Does anyone tested, or knows how long it takes to check a checkbox or radio button (normal 16px or so size - on a web application?

I know its sounds out of context, but I need such estimation to create a good UX behaviour for Backend issues.
Tried all kind of Fitts law testing, but they are empirical of course (clicking all kinds of bars and circles) and not real component, thus not providing the exact timing I am looking for.

The gory details and context:

I was approached by developers in order to "cover" backend problems.
We have a list, each row with a checkbox.
On every selection/deselection of a row, a heavy calculation process starts.
When it ends a gauge chart will be shown on top of the screen.

It means that if a user checks/unchecks 3 times - the process will be kicked 3 times, while only the **latest** process is relevant (since it reflects the most updated state).
The developers can't stop the previous processes.

My proposal was to add a timer that starts on first click, and restarting it on every other click. Only when the timer reaches X milliseconds , the calculation will start.
The UI feedback will show a calculation indication **immediately** after the first click, but actually calculation will start after timer reached the X milliseconds.

So I need to know what is the X milliseconds that might assume the user finished the clicking phase. I know, it's very hard to estimate (user reads the row details, scans , scrolls, etc), but at least I want to eliminate cases when calculation starts when user checks two adjacents rows, or checks and uncheck same checkbox.
Cost for the user - he will wait always the X second.

**Long story short - what should X be (*except for twitter logo*)? how long it takes to check/uncheck a checkbox or two adjacent checkbox.**

Thanks,

Iris

Comment: Yes, please provide more context

Comment: @VitalyMijiritsky  I have edited my initial question with the context :-)

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be assuming that their goal is to mark the boxes as quickly as possible, meaning that they don't take time to think and to make a conscious choice whether the box should be checked or not.

Since most of the delay between the actions is typically likely to be due to their thought process and not to the physical action of marking the checkbox, I don't think that your solution addresses the problem. It might even be that it makes it worse - because instead of activating the process right away, it delays it even more. This should be weighed against the probability that the second checking will fall within X seconds of the first one.

In terms of solutions, I would look at more "classical" UX toolkit. E.g. it sounds like a submit button may be in order, so they can mark all the boxes before launching the calculation? Or, if each box depends on the result of the previous one, maybe they should be revealed in a specific order, or disabled as long as the process is not complete. In short, I would look at the overall UX of the page before resorting to tweaking calculation times, it sounds like the current solution could be optimized to better reflect the actual use cases.

Comment: @IrisGreen, this is your answer. The choice for the immediate calculation on selection sounds like it's chosen "because it can" or because it is fancy and modern. But it won't feel very fancy and modern when the delay is problematic for that design. Trying to move forward with this design will only give you more (X-Y) problems and questions like yours here. If reducing the delay to an acceptable time isn't possible due to technical constraints then you have take a step back and rethink how you want your users to experience the delay.

Comment: @VitalyMijiritsky: I know this is part from being perfect., and the user will often scan and read before ticking the checkbox.  My solution is to prevent two processes triggered one after another because quick check and uncheck of the same row (which happens often). Submit button is not an option. The user get a list (which they already know), with %censored. Unchecking a row with highly censored rate, impacts all other rows calculation and overall censored data. It has to be done one by one...The user wants all the rows by definition, but need to uncheck some due privacy issues.

Comment: @IrisGreen I see two options here. Either they need to know the result of their action before they decide on the next one, or they don't. If it's the former, then all rows can be disabled until the calculation is done, which solves your problem of overlapping processes. If it's the latter, let them check a bunch of rows and then run the calculation (aka Submit). Hypothetically you can combine the two by creating two different selection methods (select & run vs. add to selection to run as a group).

Answer (score 1):

There is no universal measurement here. Take the following checkboxes:

```
[ ] I agree to the terms of service and privacy policy
[x] Disable this checkbox to not remain unsubscribed to our newsletter
```

The first one you can expect people to click as soon as they have parsed the word "terms", as it's just a routine movement at this point whenever they sign up for anything. The second one is intentionally difficult and needs some time to cancel out the negatives and understand what it actually does - and even then they might not be entirely sure.

The same thing is true for your case - if the user just wants to select 4 adjacent rows to show the graph for, that's going to be extremely quick. If they first need to parse what's in the rows before making their selection, that's going to be much slower.

> On every selection/deselection of a row [...] a gauge chart will be shown on top of the screen.

Are you sure that this is desired behavior? If I'm imagining myself in a process selecting the correct rows from a a complex table, the last thing I want is to have a large, colorful region of the screen change all the time I do anything. Replacing immediate action with a "calculate chart" button the user can press once they're done doing their selections might benefit both your devs and your users.

---

But let's say we actually wanted to figure out what X should be - how long do we wait until actual processing?

First, we need to measure the first click on a checkbox. This is our t=0, we want to figure out how quickly people check their *second* checkbox.

In a simple case where there only are 2 checkboxes, I'd expect a pattern somewhat like this:

[image: 2 curves, a red, short one and a blue, long one]

The red curve is people trying to click both boxes ASAP. The blue curve is people having gathered the info they needed from the first checkbox and now are trying to do something else.

The red curve is the one you want to slice. If you delay computation until the tail of the curve, you'll be solving your problem. This tail doesn't live in isolation of course - if, say, the average person in the red curve takes a full second or two, you'd have to delay your computation by so much that things would actually feel noticeably sluggish to the user. According to [Nielsen](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/response-times-3-important-limits/), response time limits are 0.1s for instant action, 1s for flow of thought and 10s for attention. You probably want to stay out of the 10s+ range.

> The developers can't stop the previous processes.

I'm reasonably certain they can if they wanted to. It may be difficult, it may be annoying and involve large refactors, it may not be priority, but it's not impossible to implement. If you've done the above tests and find things become too sluggish, you may be able to push back on them with a reasonably strong argument that their idea is unworkable.

Comment: I know also that developers can do the extra effort. However they often expect the UI to cover bad BE behaviour. This almost always NOT a good idea.And the above is just one example how to try do something which will cover only very few scenarios (quick uncheck and check for example), but certainly won't solve the issue.

Comment: The principle remains the same for a more complex setup of buttons: You measure how quickly the second checkbox is clicked relative to the first one. Which of the many options is the second doesn't matter, the average works fine to know how quickly people click the second box. You can carry this on and measure the time from the second to the third check and so on. All of these measurements will tell you how long it takes people to click the next checkbox, which you can tune your wait timer to.